# 12.10 problem - no access to programs

Tags: 12.10

Just updated my 12.04 to 12.10, my Dell Latitude 630 laptop and everything is OK.
Next my Gigabyte desktop and oops, I see no icons, no way to open terminal - can open file browser, new docs with LibreOffice and even Firefox - but not the Ubuntu programs nor the terminal. Pressing the Meta-key (or what it is called, Windows-key on my keyboard) renders nothing.
I do not have Ubuntu bootdisk (updated via UpdateManager) - what can I do?
I am a bit in the country so I cannot walk into the next shop... tried to burn a new 12.10 bootdisk from the net, but no success. Is there a way to do something without the terminal or could I possibly open the terminal manually (finding the program)?

Comment: `CTRL + ALT + T` opens a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can open terminal using Ctrl + Alt + T

I don't understnd your question. You mean your Unity and upper bar disappeared? 
I had problem like this after updating my nVidia graphic card drivers. But also got problem with resolution (dropped to 1152 x 864 from 1920 x 1080).

Comment: Thanks, I had just found out about the terminal. You have understood me right - the Unity and upper bar are not shown. It seems to be connected with my graphic card but however every thing else seems to be allright. I am now trying to get Ubuntu 12.04 disc to reinstall but as far as I can learn it might destroy all my data (which I hate). I have been trying to find out how I could possibly reinstall the update to 12.10 (as I did) to see if it could succeed second time, but have no success so far.

Comment: Ok, so I might help you :)

There is two possible solutions.

Comment: 1. Go to Software Sources > Additional Drivers. You should have few options. Just try tu use another driver from there (that helped me).

2. Make this steps to install headers:
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Hope it will help :)

(sorry for double post)

Comment: oh, I forgot, to access System Settings via terminal, type: gnome-control-center